# dexOptions is obsolete. how can i define mathchingFallbacks?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project, and a build-type i defined in some of my modules ("new-type").
since it isn't defined in all the modules, it was defined like this

```kotlin
create("new-type") {
  initWith(getByName("release"))
  dexOptions {
    setMathcingFallbacks("new-type", "release")
  }
}
```

but now, moving to AGP 7, both `dexOptions` and `setMathcingFallbacks`(in `.kts`) are deprecated.
How should i replace them?

Answer (score 0):

Now, the `ApplicationBuildType` has a the `matchingFallbacks` property directly, so:

```kotlin
create("new-type") {
  initWith(getByName("release"))
  matchingFallbacks = listOf("new-type", "release")
}
```